# CakePHP: Do not retrieve id field in find()

Tags: cakephp, find

I would like to retrieve some columns from a table, **without** the `id` column, but CakePHP keeps adding it to the `find()` array.
What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the find params to set the fields you want:

```
$this->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(), //array of conditions
    'fields' => array('field1', 'field2') //array of field names
));
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

As I noted in the comments, when retrieving related model data, cake uses the id to get the related data in the foreign table.  If you think about it, how else would CakePHP do it?

If you really *must* remove the id column, you can do so after the find call:

```
$data = $this->Model->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(), //array of conditions
));
unset($data['Model']['id']);
```

Comment: I am using the `fields` array, but it is still adding the `id` field...I tried to use an alias on that field, it adds the alias, but it also adds the `id` field.

Comment: Are you retrieving related data?  (hasOne, hasMany, etc.)  If you are, then cake *must* retrieve the id column to figure out the association.

Comment: Yes, I am retrieving related data. So, isn't there any chance to get rid of that `id`?

Comment: I tried the `unset()` method, but it doesn't get rid of the `id` field. Maybe because it is a hasMany relationship. I tried using a `foreach()` loop to achieve this, but it acts very wierdly. If I debug in the `foreach()`, the `id` is gone. But when I debug the array after the `foreach()` loop, the `id` is back again. Why is this happening?

Comment: Cake is adding the id automatically because it has to know the id in order to join related models (id is by default the foreign key in many relationship types).  If you set recursive to -1, you will stop retrieving related models, which should fix this issue.  If you need to retrieve related models in this scenario, you have your relationships setup wrong (you need to specify the foreign key in the relationship definiton, in the model class).

Comment: Thank you very much! By setting the `recursive` to `-1` the problem was solved. Thanks again!